# How can i avoid white noise on glass?

Tags: modeling, rendering, lighting

So i followed a blender guru tutorial about lightbulbs.
I got some noise in the render and don´t know why, cause i did everything as told in the tutorial. What can i do (except photoshop it away)?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried filtering glossy? It's under **Light Paths** on the render panel.

Comment: i found it. what value would you recommend?

Comment: i tried filtering glossy. the only difference is that the glowing bulb looks different.

Comment: You could try a filter of 1, but it appears to me that those white spots are not noise (specifically) but in fact reflections of that one point of light in your scene (or other lights, if you have any). So there's really no way to eliminate those, except for making them look better by rendering with more samples. Also, you could see this post for many more tips on reducing "fireflies": https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30465/16835

Comment: Another note to my above comment, it may really help to try disabling reflective and refractive caustics under Light Paths on the Render panel, as is mentioned in the post I linked to above.