# Fireflies. Where are the options for clamping in 2.8?

Tags: noise-reduction

I moved on to Blender 2.8, and I'm trying to find a way to remove the fireflies in my work. Obviously, you have to use the clamping feature to reduce the fireflies, but I just couldn't seem to find it in the 2.8 version of Blender.

If anyone who is using Blender 2.8 out there right now, how do you guys find the clamping feature in Blender 2.8 to get rid of the fireflies.

Comment: i just use the denoising option and that removes the fireflies
maybe its the clamping tho

Answer (score 4):

You have to be in cycles.
Then you will have the option in the Light paths section.

[image]

Most fireflies can be dealt with by clamping indirect light.

Be careful not to use very small values, as they will make the scene much darker.

Reaed: [Cycles: Emission Shader does not bring enough light](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45195/cycles-emission-shader-does-not-bring-enough-light/45381#45381)

Read also: [What is Clamp Direct/Indirect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93955/what-is-clamp-direct-indirect/93962#93962)

and:

[How to reduce fireflies in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles)

[What is the Reason Cycles Creates Incorrectly Colored/Firefly Artifact Pixels?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/what-is-the-reason-cycles-creates-incorrectly-colored-firefly-artifact-pixels)

[Managing/Reducing noise in a night scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30407/managing-reducing-noise-in-a-night-scene)